# What's the variable for current working directory in vim?

Tags: file, vim

In vimscript, if I want to get the value of current working directory for **current buffer** (could be changed by `:lcd`), which variable or expression would I use to fetch that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
let cwd = getcwd()
```

or

```
let cwd = fnamemodify('.', ':p')
```

. Both always return effective value for the current buffer, but determination of whether this is working directory local to buffer (i.e. changed by `:lcd`/`'autochdir'`) or global one (i.e. changed by `:cd`/untouched since vim start) is the more interesting question. I do not know the answer for it.

Comment: If I want to use the result as parameters, could I do `map <leader>f :NERDTreeToggle getcwd()<cr>`

Comment: @steven.yang You don’t need to know path to the working directory for NERDTree. Just `nnoremap \f :NERDTreeToggle .<CR>`. [Ah, and don’t use `:map` without `:nore`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html).

Comment: @steven.yang If there was no such shortcut for current directory (this is shortcut used in filenames always, not a NERDTree feature) you then had to use `:execute`: `:execute 'NERDTreeToggle' fnameescape(getcwd())<CR>`.

Comment: the reason I am tuning the NERDTreeToggle is because NERDTreeToggle will 'cache' the tree for current tab. When I change the directory with `:lcd`, the NERDTree still point to the former directory I am working on. As the `NERDTree` accept an optional params for the cwd path, I want to pass the current buffer's cwd to it. That's the source for this question.  I think your last solution with `:exec` works for me.

Comment: There is `haslocaldir()` (since 7.0.230 already).
And there's a patch on vim_dev to improve support in this regard for specific windows: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/T7hAwOUAgkQ/discussion